# Android M direct sharing

Tags: android

I have two activities and service. I'm trying to make direct sharing, but it doesn't work(

First activity that sending data

```
public class MainShareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_main);
}

public void share(View view){
    startService(new Intent(this, DirectSharePicker.class));

    EditText etShare = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sharedText);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etShare.getText().toString());

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Direct share demo"));
}
```

Activity, that catches SEND

```
public class CatchSendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_USER_ID = "userId";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int userID = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_USER_ID, -1);
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

    textView.setText(userID + ": " + sharedText);
}
```

Target service

```
public class DirectSharePicker extends ChooserTargetService {

@Override
public List<ChooserTarget> onGetChooserTargets(ComponentName componentName, IntentFilter intentFilter) {
    List<ChooserTarget> response = new LinkedList<>();
    Icon icon = Icon.createWithResource(this, R.id.icon);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        String title = "Target" + i;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatchSendActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CatchSendActivity.EXTRA_USER_ID, i);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        ChooserTarget chooserTarget = new ChooserTarget(title, icon, i, pendingIntent);
        response.add(chooserTarget);
    }
    return response;
}
```

And this is my manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <service
        android:name=".DirectSharePicker"
        android:label="SHARING!"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".CatchSendActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
            android:value=".DirectSharePicker" />

    </activity>
```

But onGetChooserTargets never called.

Comment: What happens if you just use `startActivity(intent)` rather than `startActivity(Intent.createChooser())`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, it is strange, but i moved this code out from module to application, and sharing works well now. Why? Оо

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. How did you move it from module to application?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, Intent.createChooser will make sure to display the dialog even if you had previously selected some app to be used as 'always'.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [Android Developer Pages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/chooser/ChooserTarget.html):

> The creator of a target may supply a ranking score. This score is assumed to be relative to the other targets supplied by the same query. Scores should be in the range from 0.0f (unlikely match) to 1.0f (very relevant match). Scores for a set of targets do not need to sum to 1.

Try putting some valid score instead **'i'** since i can go upto 4 as per your code.

Also, put full name of classes and services in manifest 
e.g

```
<service
    android:name="com.your.package.DirectSharePicker"
    ...
```

Instead

```
<service
    android:name=".DirectSharePicker"
    ...
```